# Does an ampersand affect sharepoint 2007 rss feed viewer

Tags: 2007, rss

Can the length title of the Feed affect the SharePoint 2007 rss feed viewer? Or can characters such as the ampersand (&) affect it?

I am getting this error:

"An unexpected error occured processing your request. Check the logs for details and correct the problem."

But the only thing that has changes has been a new story has been added to the feed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an internal RSS feed within Sharepoint? If so, the likely culprit is that you are running NTLM authentication in the farm. The only way to have RSS feeds work successfully is to be running Kerberos authentication or to be using an external public feed.

Comment: It's an external feed...It was working correctly and there was a new feed added and it started to give me the error.